# Read API Json Data

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a windows console application to read Json api data, retrieve all the type="folder" items and then save the data to database. How to access to the properties of the Json data? 
Json data format:

```
    {
 asset:{
        path:{
                Children:[
                         0:{
                            id:xxxx,
                            type: folder

                            },
                         1:{
                            id:xxxxx,
                            type: folder
                            },
                         2:{
                            id:xxxx,
                            type: page

                            }
                            ...
                        ]
                }

       },
success:ok
}
```

FolderModel:

```
public class FolderModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

//main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Task T = new Task(ApiCall);
                T.Start();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

//apicall

static async void ApiCall()
        {

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://apiurl/");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FolderModel>(responseBody);
                //items id and type are null here. how to retrieve those information ??

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON and c# model are not identical first you need to create models to deserialize json

```
   public class FolderModel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Path
    {
        public List<FolderModel> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Asset
    {
        public Path path { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseModel
    {

        public Asset asset { get; set; }
        public string Success { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you can access deserialize using

```
   var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(responseBody);
```

Now you can acess properties using linq or foreach loop

**Using Linq**

```
  var folderResponse =  response.asset.path.Children.Select(x => new 
                                    FolderModel { id = x.id, type = x.type });

  //or you can access like this if you need to get all fields
  var folderResponse = response.asset.path.Children.Select(x => x);
```

**ForEach**

```
            foreach (var folder in response.asset.path.Children)
            {
                //folder.id
                //folder.type
            }
```

JSON to parse

```
{
  "asset": {
    "path": {
      "Children": [
        {
          "id": "xxxx",
          "type": "folder"
        },
        {
          "id": "xxxxx",
          "type": "folder"
        },
        {
          "id": "xxxx",
          "type": "page"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "success": "ok"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got error message "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here I changed your code to  var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(responseBody); var folderResponse =  myData.Asset.Path.Childrens.ChildrenList.Select(x=>x); because there are red lines under response and Children. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need to initialize children list in constructor

Comment: I did this public partial class Children
    {
        public List<FolderModel> ChildrenList { get; set; }

        public Children() { }
    } and it returns the same error object is null.

Comment: Can you give me the exact json which you are parsing there should not be numbers before children like 0,1,2

Comment: I have updated the code and its working on my end and let me know its working for you or not

Comment: It has different error now. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'asset.path.children[0].path'

Comment: I updated the json file. The FolderModel path is a object instead of string. That's the error place.